# Could not find API compiler-cli, function VERSION

Tags: angular, github, npm, angular6

When i download a repository from github to run angular project i run command `npm install` to add node modules in this project then when i run `ng serve` i get this error:

[image]

> Error: Could not find API compiler-cli, function VERSION
>
> at_error(C:\Users\Daniyal\node_modules@ngtools\webpack\src\ngtools_api.js:8:11
>   atgetApiMember(C:\Users\Daniyal\node_modules@ngtools\webpack\src\ngtools_api.js:11:32)
>     at Object.
>   (C:\Users\Daniyal\node_modules@ngtools\webpack\src\ngtools_api.js:50:19)
>     at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)   at
>   Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)  at Module.load
>   (module.js:565:32)
>
> at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)     at Function.Module._load
>   (module.js:497:3)     at Module.require (module.js:596:17)    at require
>   (internal/module.js:11:18)    at Object.
>   (C:\Users\Daniyal\node_modules@ngtools\webpack\src\angular_compiler_plugin.js:28:23)
>   at Module._compile (module.js:652:30) at Object.Module._extensions..js
>   (module.js:663:10) at Module.load (module.js:565:32) at tryModuleLoad
>   (module.js:505:12) at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)

You can see from here also:

> Could not find API compiler-cli, function VERSION

Comment: any robust solution for this? We also are facing the same error

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have `@angular/compiler` in the npm dependencies list in `package.json` and the package is installed.